# Jquery animate with css float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

i have a problem with my code, the width seems to work but the float no.
Here it is:

**HERE IS AN EXAMPLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/v82ck/

**THE PROBLEM: the float property on the menu when hovering doesnt change, i want the line below each menu element to slide below the element when hovering that menu element.**

the code isnt complicated, i just dont know what is happening

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#line-menu').css({ //initial state
        'float': 'left',
         'width' : $('#menu-1').width(),
    });
    $('#menu-1').hover(function(){ //first menu element
        var width = $(this).width();

        $('#line-menu').animate({
            'float': 'left',
            'width' : width
        },  "slow");
    });
    $('#menu-2').hover(function(){ //second menu element

        var width = $(this).width();

        $('#line-menu').animate({ 
            'float': 'none', 
            'width' : width
        },  "slow");
    });
    $('#menu-3').hover(function(){ //third menu element

        var width = $(this).width();

        $('#line-menu').animate({
            'float': 'right',
            'width' : width
        },  "slow");
    });
});
```

the css so you can see it

**CSS:**

```
#line-menu{
    height: 3px;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    background: #CC0000;
    margin-left:55px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:3px;
}
#line-menu-container{
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 617px;
    max-width: 1113px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

this is the part that is conflicting

**HTML:**

```
<header> 
    <div id='menu'>
        <div class='menu-element' id='menu-1'>HORARIOS</div>
        <div class='menu-element' id='menu-2'>UBICACI&Oacute;N</div>
        <div class='menu-element' id='menu-3'>CONTACTO</div>
    </div>
</header>

   <div id='line-menu-container'> //the line contained in a container just to fix the centered position
       <div id='line-menu' ></div>
   </div>
```

the jquery library that i use is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

i ask you guys because i dont really know how to fix it...

---

**EDIT:** It's been a while (2 years). If i had to do this again, i will go for the use of an abstraction, such as using a framework like twitter bootstrap. There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a live example and define the actual problem.

Comment: thanks ive posted a live example and defined the actual problem @elclanrs

Comment: Would you like something this one http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/ ?

Comment: yess, i will give it a try and let you know, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `float` property for absolutely positioned elements. in fact it doesn't change anything,  use `position: relative` instead.

It seems you want to position the element according to the `width` and `left` offset of the hovered element, you can use `offset` method and CSS `left` property instead of `float` property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var $first = $('#menu-1'), $line = $('#line-menu');
    $line.css({
        'width' : $first.width(),
        'left'  : $first.offset().left
    });
    $('#menu > div').mouseenter(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            width = $this.width(),
            left  = $this.offset().left;

        $line.stop().animate({
            'left'  : left,
            'width' : width
        },  "slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dwJR/

Comment: @GuidoCelada Why do you want to use `float` property there?

Comment: because the menu elements are 3 and they adapt to the screen size better using the float property.

Comment: the problem with the left property is that its static and when i change the size of the window, the line doesnt stay under the menu element