# Why doesn't changing float atttribute inside animate work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my CSS code for an html element

```
.img_container{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 260px;
    float: none;
}
```

And I want to change it to

```
.img_container{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 260px;
    float: left;
}
```

Using JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menulist").hide();
    $(".hor_bar").hide();
    $(".myimg").mouseup(function(){
        $(".img_container").animate({
            'margin-left': '50px',
            'float': 'left'
        },600,'easeInOutQuart',
        function(){
            $(".menulist").show();
            $(".hor_bar").show();
        });         
    });
});
```

Where CSS of menulist is

```
.menulist{
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 125px;
}
```

and of hor_bar is

```
.hor_bar{
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #939393;
    margin-top: 304px;
}
```

Although this JQuery does change the `margin-left` to `50px` but `'float': 'left'` shows no effect at all.

Am I missing an important concept here ?

Comment: You can only animate unit values, not keywords.

Comment: How do you expect the animation of `float`?? There's no intermediate values; there's left, none, and right (and some others). Margin can be animated because you have a range of pixels (a number)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085888/jquery-animate-with-css-float and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372315/how-to-animate-floatleft-divs

Comment: Then how to change the float value through jquery? I want to change the value of float to left after the animation.

Comment: @user3606997 use .css('float', 'left') inside of the callback function of the .animate call.

Comment: @ArrayKnight Thanks, it worked. And I got to know that in animate we cannot force string valued attributes to animate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate keywords, only numbers.

Here is a list of all animatable CSS properties: [CSS animatable properties](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/).